# What kind of JOIN should I use here?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, html, database

I'm new to JOINS in MySql.

I have six tables: t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6.
And I also have one main table: `main_table`.
TOTAL 7 TABLES!

The first column of ALL tables is called `classified_id`.

If the user searches for "cars" then the main table will match everything in table t1 (which is the cars table) where classified_id is the same in both tables.

So:

```
   SELECT * FROM main_table, t1 WHERE main_table.classified_id=t1.classified_id
```

This works fine, although I am not sure this is the way to join here. Performance is an issue in my case!

However, here is my problem.
Whenever **ALL CLASSIFIEDS** are searched, then I need to match the `main_table.classified_id` to the other tables `classified_id` column and get every classified there is.

How should this query be made up?

```
    SELECT * FROM main_table, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6 // I have this so far which is not much!
```

If you need more input just ask and I will update this Q.

Thanks

EDIT:
Table setup:

```
     main_table:              t1:
     ID(PK)                   ID (PK)
     classified_id -> 25      classified_id     ->   25
     category  -> CARS        year     ->    1997
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when in one of the tables there are no record with classified_id. Because this is the main criteria which join type to use.

Comment: It sounds like t1-t6 are classified entries, each with 2 columns, id and value, where 'value' is something like '2008 Camry. Runs good.' Is that right?

Comment: then return 0! No matches found!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the row would exist in all tables (i.e. every table has a row for a specific classified_id), then you would use an inner join:

```
SELECT 
   m.classified_id
   ,m.category
   ,t1.year
   ,........
FROM 
   main_table m
   INNER JOIN t1 ON m.classified_id = t1.classified_id
   INNER JOIN t2 ON m.classified_id = t2.classified_id
   INNER JOIN t3 ON m.classified_id = t3.classified_id
   INNER JOIN t4 ON m.classified_id = t4.classified_id
   INNER JOIN t5 ON m.classified_id = t5.classified_id
   INNER JOIN t6 ON m.classified_id = t6.classified_id
```

If the row does not exist in every table, then you'd use LEFT JOINS so that rows are not dropped

Comment: That will return an error, because of using `SELECT *` - there are column name collisions with `classified_id`.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
   SELECT mt.*,
          t1.*,
          t2.*,
          t3.*,
          t4.*,
          t5.*,
          t6.*
     FROM MAIN_TABLE mt
LEFT JOIN TABLE_1 t1 ON t1.classified_id = mt.classified_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2 ON t2.classified_id = mt.classified_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_3 t3 ON t3.classified_id = mt.classified_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_4 t4 ON t4.classified_id = mt.classified_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_5 t5 ON t5.classified_id = mt.classified_id
LEFT JOIN TABLE_6 t6 ON t6.classified_id = mt.classified_id
```

I used `LEFT JOIN`s because if `JOIN` was used - records would be omitted that did not have a supporting record in at least one of the t1/2/3/4/5/6 tables.  You might find [this link helpful for understanding JOINs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).